# How do get updated with AWS Status Dashboard, without checking manually?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, alert, dashboard, datadog

I am looking to build some certain types of alerts for https://status.aws.amazon.com/, to get constantly updated on the status for certain services.

Answer (score 3):

There are RSS feeds available on the website that you've linked. You can use those feeds with a feed reader or an integration in your favourite messaging app (e.g., Slack) to get notifications of new messages.

You can get RSS feeds by service, or [use the global RSS feed for all updates](https://status.aws.amazon.com/rss/all.rss).